# Running Windows Mixed Reality on MBP in Parallels

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, windows-mixed-reality

Is it possible to make Windows Mixed Reality Portal run on a virtual Win10 in Parallels 14 Pro on a 2018 MacBook Pro with Radeon Pro Vega 16 4 GB graphics?

Currently it complains about the gfx driver:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You may try to enable developer mode in Windows and then start the Portal with developer's configuration. But please bear in mind, that the result isn't guarantied or even tested.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to whether it *runs,* but you *can* skip the requirements check<sup>1</sup> with registry settings. Add one or both of the following `DWORD`s, set to `1`, at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic`:

- [`AllowFailedSystemChecks`](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-mixed-reality-hardware-checks/): This presumably lets you click "Continue" even if the requirements check fails.
- [`FirstRunSucceeded`](https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsMR/comments/7kj5i7/cant_install_windows_mixed_reality/dsqp19f/): This will let you trick WMR into *not performing the check at all.* This was important for a friend whose requirements check would hang indefinitely. He never got either pass or fail messages.

Comment with your results for the good of the internet.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Here be dragons.</sub>